# Send schedule email in firebase cloud functions flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a system built in Flutter. When a user subscribes I want to

- Generate a PDF file ( invoice ) in flutter using [Pdf creation library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)
- send (monthly) an email with that PDF file

1- My question is how to trigger the cloud schedule function

- Date store in cloud firestore that I need to for generating the pdf file
- generate the PDF file will be in Flutter
- sending scheduled emails will be in the cloud function

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to trigger them they will run automatically on given time period  like cron

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: This will be the cloud function, I will call it from the Flutter side the first time and it will run automatically after a period, but how to call the Flutter function to generate a pdf file?

Comment: I don't think you need to call it. 
You just put your code inside that you want to execute, like in this example you this function will execute in every 5 minutes.

More over if you have heavier workloads you can consider using task along with schedule function

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions

Comment: You just need to deploy it only.

Comment: This is JavaScript code it will run every 5 minutes, I need to run Flutter code every 5 minutes

Comment: On flutter side you can use Timer Class

Comment: It should be in server side. what if the device or user close the app

Comment: Right approach is to do this on server side not the client side,